# Is there a way to get the 'value' event only when data is changed?

Tags: firebase

According to the Firebase documentation:

> The 'value' event is used to read the entire contents of a Firebase location. It is triggered once with the initial data, and again every time the data changes.

Is there a way to get all the data on the snapshot only when data is changed?

The reason behind this is because I am using Firebase for collab mode only which means when collab is enabled there is data already that came from my DB which should match the the FB data. I could just ignore the first callback (the init callback) but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We actually intentionally do not differentiate between initial state and updates. We're a synchronization service, rather than a messaging service.

You can definitely simply ignore the first callback. That should work fine.

The other approach would be to use Firebase as your primary datastore, and have your servers populate the data in Firebase rather than serving the data to the end user directly.

Comment: Yeah, eventually that could happen but def not now. Thanks for the answer!